# Add special characters (html encoded) in CRM Dynamics 4.0 SiteMap file

Tags: sitemap, dynamics-crm, crm

I would like to know if this is possible to add special character into the CRM (4.0) SiteMap entity (SiteMap XML files). I mean when we modify the menu located on the left I would like to have some HTML encoded character. By example ® or some other special characters.

I tried to do the following:

```
<Area Id="MyArea" Icon="/_imgs/resourcecenter_24x24.gif">
    <Titles>
        <Title LCID="1033" Title="Title english &amp;reg;"/>
        <Title LCID="1036" Title="Title french &amp;reg;"/>
    </Titles> 
    <Descriptions>
        <Description LCID="1033" Description="Description EN &amp;reg;"/>
        <Description LCID="1036" Description="Description FR &amp;reg;"/>
    </Descriptions>
    <Group Id="MyArea_Group">
        <SubArea Id="mySubArea" 
           Url="https://toMyWebSite/Page.aspx" AvailableOffline="false" >
           <Titles>
            <Title LCID="1033" Title="My Item"/>
            <Title LCID="1036" Title="My Item French"/>
           </Titles>
        </SubArea>
    </Group>
</Area>
```

This actually show "Title English &reg;" in my left menu area instead of "Title English ®".

Does anyone have a solution?

(Note: I already tried to put the character directly with "alt-0174" but it didn't worked.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** My initial response was incorrect. Use the numbered HTML escape (in this case `&#174;`) to get those characters into the sitemap.

Just put `&reg;` instead of what you have. The `&amp;` is being escaped and then it just outputs the characters `reg;` because that isn't an HTML escape code.

Comment: That won't work, because & is a reserved character in XML files. So when you will try to import your sitemap.xml to CRM it will say it doesn't respect the schema (xsd).

Comment: Ah, I see. Do '&#174;' instead. Just tried it locally and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Can you update your answer so it's clear :D. Thank's again.